# What is "identification assumptions" in econometrics?

Tags: econometrics, identifiability

I'm starting to study econometrics from Wooldridge's book. But some doubts arise regarding to the role of Conditional Expectations in Econometrics.

Wooldridge says that although it is not always explicitly stated, the goal of most applied econometric studies is to estimate or test hypotheses about the conditional expectation. So, a substantial portion of research in econometric methodology can be interpreted as finding ways to estimate conditional expectations in the numerous settings that arise in economic applications.

In each case there is a conditional expectation (CE) of interest, but it  generally involves variables for which the econometrician cannot collect data or requires an experiment that cannot be carried out.

So it seems to me that a solution is coming. Under additional assumptions—generally called identification assumptions—we can sometimes recover the structural conditional expectation originally of interest, even if we cannot observe all of the desired controls.

My question then is: what are these identification assumptions? More important is: in what sense do we recover the structural conditional expectation originally of interest, even if we cannot observe all of the desired controls?

I would like to see some examples to better understand and fix intuition.

Comment: "My question then is: what are these identification assumptions?" it depends on your model. What is your model?

Comment: Suposse a linear model and a non-linear model.

Comment: Are you saying that you would like us to explain the concept of 'identifiability', or do you already understand this concept and you want to know the particular identification assumptions in this form of model?

Comment: From what I read, the concept of identifiability is different between linear and non-linear models. What I do know is that for the case of the linear model, identifiability consists in exposing my population parameter as a function of population moments. But I would like to know your definition and see some examples as well. More than that and also very important,  in what sense do we recover the structural conditional expectation originally of interest, even if we cannot observe all of the desired controls? Examples?

Comment: "Suposse a linear model and a non-linear model." <- that's not enough information. I'm going to flag this for being unclear.

Comment: Ok, do you have a example with linear model?